# change texture at runtime

Tags: c#, unity

How can I change the texture at runtime. I have done changing the label(text) at runtime. The following code is used

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class switchtime : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    private bool showLabel = false;
    private bool showLabe2 = false;
    private bool showLabe3 = false;
    private bool showLabe4 = false;

    public void Start() {
        Invoke("ToggleLabel", 1);
        Invoke("ToggleLabel2", 3);
        Invoke("ToggleLabel3",6 );
        Invoke("ToggleLabel4", 9);
    }

    public void ToggleLabel() {
        showLabel = !showLabel;

    }
    public void ToggleLabel2() {

        showLabe2 = !showLabe2;
    }
    public void ToggleLabel3() {

        showLabe3 = !showLabe3;
    }
    public void ToggleLabel4() {

        showLabe4 = !showLabe4;
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if (showLabel) {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(300, 200, 100, 20), "Copying window file..");

        }
        if (showLabe2) {

            GUI.Label(new Rect(40, 40, 100, 20), "Epanding windows file..");
        }
        if (showLabe3) {

            GUI.Label(new Rect(80, 80, 100, 20), "Installing Feature..");
        }
        if (showLabe4) {

            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 20), "Installing Updates");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to change the GUITexture at runtime. How can do this? Can anybody help me in coding?

Here is some changes I made. I worked on changing the gameObject when mouse is placed on it. This is the code I applied and its working for me

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class change : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject newSprite;

    private Vector3 currentSpritePosition;
    void update()
    {    
    }

    void Start()
    {    
        newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
        currentSpritePosition = transform.position;

        //then make it invisible
        renderer.enabled = false;

        //give the new sprite the position of the latter
        newSprite.transform.position = currentSpritePosition;

        //then make it visible
        newSprite.renderer.enabled = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit(){
        //just the reverse process
        renderer.enabled = true;
        newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, in same code I need to set a time so that the text get loaded without the mouse click. I mean a particular time to load each text one after the another.

Here  is my screen shot
[image]

Here I have placed the image one below the another,when the mouse is hovered on it it will change the text from bold to normal text.Changes process stated in (image 2,3).That code I posted is working for me.

Comment: The last part is not clear, are you wanting to reveal text on a mouse click? Are you trying to animate text after a mouse click? Are there any examples of the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the above example i have done and got the object changed when the mouse is pointed on it.Above I have placed the scrren shot

Comment: From the image,mage(1) first text is normal font and all other are in bold font.When the mouse is moved on the text it will change from bold to normal text.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you are doing that sort of work in Unity3D but alright :) Instead of doing an edit please create an answer with that content and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can load resources from a folder called "Resources" using this:

```
Texture texture = Resources.Load(textureName);
guiTexture.texture = texture;
```

Nice and simple. If you want to find a particular texture using a named reference you can use:

```
Texture texture = Resources.Load(textureName);
GameObject.Find("NameRef").guiTexture.texture = texture;
```

You can even shorthand it to:

```
GameObject.Find("NameRef").guiTexture.texture
    = Resources.Load(textureName, typeof(Texture));
```

EDIT:

You can also apply this to an attached texture:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class switchtime : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUITexture myGuiTexture;

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        // Blah blah do other stuff

        ApplyMyTexture();
    }

    public void ApplyMyTexture()
    {
        myGuiTexture.texture
            = Resources.Load(textureName, typeof(Texture));
    }
}
```

You can change the function names to suit your usage.

Comment: Hope my question was not clear

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Your question was clear. You want to change a texture on your GUI at runtime, this is how you do it. This also assumes that you have added a Texture to your scene. If you add a GUITexture to the scene and give it a name you can reference it using these functions. You can also add it as a property on your game object that this script is attached to so that you can reference it directly.

Comment: above I have edited my question and placed my screenshot.Hope it will be more clear